# Get event name from Action<T>

Tags: c#, events, reflection, action

I would like to be able to do that:

```
Verify.EventIsHooked(a => a.Event1 += null);
```

Having this scenario:

```
class A
{
    public event EventHandler Event1;
}

class static Verify
{
    public static void EventIsHooked<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        // What comes here to extract the event name?
    }
}
```

How can I extract the `Event1` name from the expression?

Thanks

PD: I know how to check if an event is hooked or not. I just need to extract the event name.

**Edit**:

The idea behind is to be able to get the delegates attached to an event in order to determine if an event has been hooked/unhooked in a unit test, without passing the event name as string to the reflection call.

[Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) uses lambdas like `a => a.Event1 += null` when raising events, since it looks like the only way to pass an event in an expression.

Comment: Even if you could do this, `T` could contain many events, and you have no way to disambiguate.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "How can I extract the Event1 name from the expression?" -- What expression? `Verify.EventIsHooked(a => a.Event1 += null);` compiles to roughly `static void __compiler_generated_function(A a) { a.Event1 += null; } Verify.EventIsHooked(new Action<A>(__compiler_generated_function));`, and the expression `new Action<A>(__compiler_generated_function)` doesn't contain `Event1` anywhere. You've taken a few steps on a road that doesn't lead you to your desired destination, you'll need to take a few steps back.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've added some information in order to clarify the intention.